# Jersey - Producing JSON Strings with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

When I want to return JSON in my service, with the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotation, it works well for POJO. (I am using Jackson, as explained in the Jersey's documentation).

But if I return a simple String, the result is not really what I expected. The String is returned but with no quotes to encapsulate it; thus, I am not able to parse it in my JavaScript client using JQuery.

Is this the normal behavior? Is there a way to add the quotes to the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply construct `JSONObject`:

```
 JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
 myObject.JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
 try {
   myObject.put("name", "Agamemnon");
   myObject.put("age", 32);
 } 
 catch (JSONException ex) {
   LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error ...", ex);
 }
```

Comment: +1 - and here is the reference link: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

The JSONObject class can be use to create objects to be translated JSON.

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 try {
   json.put("name", "Bob");
 } catch (JSONException ex) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but it is better to add a brief explanation than just plopping down code.